# How can I select the resources of my application prgramatically?

Tags: android, multilingual, android-resources

I know if I define two resources `layout-en` and `layout-fr`, Android selects the best-matching resources according to the user language selection in his device settings. Now I want to force Android to select a special resource according to my application settings.

For example the default language of my user's device is English and I have 2 options in my application for user to select his application language and assume he selects the french.

How can I force the Android to use `fr` resources without any changes in user's device settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the locale to french. Try something like this

```
    Configuration c = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    c.locale = yourLocale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(c, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Does it set the locale of the whole of my application?

Comment: Also (not sure) I think you will need to set android:configChanges="locale" for every Activity in the Manifest.

Comment: no .. but if any activity is already running that's resource will not be changed.. you need to restart that ..

Answer (score 0):

try using [Locale.setDefault( Locale.FRANCE )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29)